# Registered sign in Sphinx

Tags: php, special-characters, sphinx

How can I tell Sphinx that my document has symbols like ®?

Sphinx doesn't show this title "surf® pure", but the title was shown "surf�pure".

� "unknown character" was shown instead of ® character.

Comment: Is the file properly stored as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes,it is stored as UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

I forgot using this command in `sphinx.conf`.

```
sql_query_pre = set names utf8
```